# Multiple $scope.$watch not working in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone explain why only the first $watch below is firing within the same controller? Both the inputs are text boxes with each ng-model assigned. (thanks in advance)

```
$scope.$watch('search', function() {
   if ($scope.watch !== ""){
       var filter = "{'name':{'$regex':'(?i).*"+$scope.search+".*'}}";
       fetch(filter);
      };
});


$scope.$watch('id', function() {
    if ($scope.id !== ""){
        var filter = "{'id':{'$regex':'(?i).*"+$scope.id+".*'}}";
        fetch2(filter);
    };
});
```

Comment: Looks OK to me. Have you tried `console.log`'s within each watcher & condition statement?

Comment: You have `$scope.watch` in your `if` statement. Did you mean `$scope.search` ?

Comment: yeah console log shows nothing for it, but strangely I am finding it will fire (and work ok) if the earlier 'search' model has been populated. Both functions return to the same model but I presumed that should be fine.

Comment: Sergey, indeed I did, thanks. Hasn't made any difference re the latter firing but thank you.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or smth like that?

Comment: Begging your pardon, on checking my backend log I can see the http call being made successfully. So my issue must actually lie in my html rendering of the response. Many thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax and see what you will get in the console

```
$scope.$watch('id', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(oldVal, newVal);
});
```

if log is OK, why dont you try with the `newVal` like this

```
$scope.$watch('id', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== ""){
        var filter = "{'id':{'$regex':'(?i).*"+newVal+".*'}}";
        fetch2(filter);
    };
});
```

Edited

Comment: Yordan, it logs the original and new value in the console log as expected

Comment: Ok, so why dont you try with the `newVal`? I've edited my answer.

Comment: Begging your pardon, thanks to your advice re using newVal and oldVal, I was convince it was indeed firing and on checking my backend log I can see the http call being made successfully. So my issue must actually lie in my html rendering of the response. Many thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this
var deregWatchGroup = $scope.$watchGroup(['1stmodelValue', '2ndmodelvalue'], function (newValues, oldValues) {
         console.log(newValues[0], oldValues[0]); //for 1st model value
         console.log(newValues[1], oldValues[1]); //for 2nd model value
         // here you can handle your stuff
 });
  //destroying watch
 $scope.$on('$destroy', deregWatchGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

To watch multiple scope in the same controller, you can use:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['search', 'id'], function(newValues, oldValues) {

 newValues[0] -> $scope.search 
 newValues[1] -> $scope.id 

// Then perform your operations.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. To answer, the issue was in my html rendering of the results and the root cause was my own idiocy. I has an extraneous ng-show which was hiding the results.